# Data.Text.Text and quasiquoting

Tags: haskell

I have a parser which parses to an ast which contains Text values. I
am trying to use this parser with quasiquoting, but the implementation
of Data for Text is incomplete. I've attached a smallish test case, when I try to compile Text.hs I get:

Text.hs:17:9:
    Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
      Data.Text.Text.toConstr
      Code: Language.Haskell.TH.Quote.quoteExp expr " test "

Is there a way to get this working?

I read through the discussion here: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-January/072379.html

It seems that no-one has found a proper solution to this issue? Also, I tried the Data instance given there and it didn't work, I have no idea how to fix it (or how to use it since the text package already has a Data instance for Text). I don't really understand a lot of the generics stuff and how it works.

The only solution I have so far is to give up using Text in the ast and go back to using String.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
module Syntax where

import Data.Data
import Data.Text

data Expr = Iden Text
          | Num Integer
          | AntiIden Text
            deriving (Eq,Show,Data,Typeable)


---------------------

module Parser where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Identity
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Text.Parsec hiding (many, optional, (<|>), string, label)
import Text.Parsec.Language
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as P
import Text.Parsec.Text ()

import Syntax

parseExpr :: T.Text -> Either ParseError Expr
parseExpr s =
  runParser expr () "" s

expr :: ParsecT T.Text () Identity Expr
expr =
  whiteSpace >> choice
  [do
   _ <- char '$'
   AntiIden <$> identifier
  ,Num <$> natural
  ,Iden <$> identifier
  ]

identifier :: ParsecT T.Text () Identity T.Text
identifier = T.pack <$> P.identifier lexer

natural :: ParsecT T.Text () Identity Integer
natural = P.natural lexer

lexer :: P.GenTokenParser T.Text () Identity
lexer = P.makeTokenParser langDef

whiteSpace :: ParsecT T.Text () Identity ()
whiteSpace = P.whiteSpace lexer

langDef :: GenLanguageDef T.Text st Identity
langDef = P.LanguageDef
               { P.commentStart   = "{-"
               , P.commentEnd     = "-}"
               , P.commentLine    = "--"
               , P.nestedComments = True
               , P.identStart     = letter <|> char '_'
               , P.identLetter    = alphaNum <|> oneOf "_"
               , P.opStart        = P.opLetter langDef
               , P.opLetter       = oneOf "+-*/<>="
               , P.reservedOpNames= []
               , P.reservedNames  = []
               , P.caseSensitive  = False
               }


-------------------


module Quasi where

import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Data.Generics
import qualified Data.Text as T

import Syntax
import Parser (parseExpr)

expr :: QuasiQuoter
expr = QuasiQuoter {quoteExp = prs
                   ,quotePat = undefined
                   ,quoteType = undefined
                   ,quoteDec = undefined}
  where
    prs :: String -> Q Exp
    prs s = p s
            >>= dataToExpQ (const Nothing
                            `extQ` antiExpE
                           )
    p s = either (fail . show) return (parseExpr $ T.pack s)

antiExpE :: Expr -> Maybe ExpQ
antiExpE v = fmap varE (antiExp v)

antiExp :: Expr -> Maybe Name
antiExp (AntiIden v) = Just $ mkName $ T.unpack v
antiExp _ = Nothing

----------------------------

-- test.hs:

{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}

import Syntax
import Quasi

test,test1,test2 :: Expr

-- works
test = [expr| 1234 |]

-- works
test1 = let stuff = Num 42
        in [expr| $stuff |]

-- doesn't work
test2 = [expr| test |]

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show test2
```

Solution: add this function using extQ to the dataToExpQ call:

```
handleText :: T.Text -> Maybe ExpQ
handleText x =
    -- convert the text to a string literal
    -- and wrap it with T.pack
    Just $ appE (varE 'T.pack) $ litE $ StringL $ T.unpack x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `extQ` for `handleText` where `handleText` explicitly takes Text to an ExpQ, rather than going through generic machinery.

Here's one for Strings, for example, that renders them more efficiently than as explicit cons cells:

```
      handleStr :: String -> Maybe (TH.ExpQ)
      handleStr x = Just $ TH.litE $ TH.StringL x
```

Comment: thanks, I added a version for text to the question above which compiles and runs fine now, is this what you'd recommend?

Comment: That's really useful: was just having exactly the same problem with ByteStrings.  Your solution works perfectly for expressions, though I could only get patterns to work by using something like: `bSPat x = Just $ litP $ StringL $ B.unpack x` and having OverloadedStrings enabled in the modules that were using the quasiquoter.